# Display worksheet from xlam file

Tags: excel, add-in, excel-2013, excel-addins

I have a workbook with an .xlam included in it, when I view the VBA I see this structure of the .xlaml

> VBAProject(Helper.xlam)
>   Microsoft Excel Objects
>     Masterinfo(MasterInfo)
>     Sheet1 (Reg)
>     ThisWorkbook
>   Forms
>     Form1
>   Modules
>     Module1
>   Class Modules
>     cm1

How can I display the worksheets MasterInfo & sheet1 to view the contents?

Answer (score 6):

In the VBA editor, find the file name of your XLAM file under the project window ( + R if it's not open already). Click on ThisWorkbook and the properties window will show the properties for that workbook (F4 opens the properties window if it's not already).

Change the IsAddin to FALSE and the worksheets should appear. Change it back after making your edits and before your final save.